# How do i solve Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'PigeonParser.h' file not found?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, android-studio

With upgrade to the latest xcode, while trying to run app on iphone through android studio, I am getting following error.

Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'PigeonParser.h' file not found
/Users/aresrana/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.11.0/ios/Classes/PigeonParser.m:4:8

**I tried adding the pigeon dependency, but could not solve the issue.**

Comment: I had the same problem, I fix it by following the 3 steps described in my answer to the same question asked on stack overflow : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77313848/14360314

Answer (score 2):

In my case with a Flutter project reason was that I have copied a custom repository from another project, and that repository contains a pubspec.yaml file, that generates 3 other files when you are getting dependencies for this pubspec.yaml file.

I have just deleted those files, in my case:

- .flutter-plugins
- .flutter-plugins-dependencies
- pubspec.lock

and it generated new ones, after that everything worked perfectly.

Maybe it helps someone else...