# Flutter: Failed to build iOS app - PigeonParser.h file not found

Tags: flutter, xcode

Suddenly I started getting this error while building the project:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'PigeonParser.h' file not found
/Users/alehhutnikau/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.11.0/ios/Classes/PigeonParser.m:4:8


Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

I tried `flutter clean`, reinitializing the iOS project, but nothing helps. Has anyone encountered something similar before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Try downgrading the firebase dependencies to the following:

```
cloud_firestore: 4.9.2
firebase_core: 2.16.0
firebase_storage: 11.2.7
firebase_auth: 4.10.0
firebase_messaging: 14.6.8
firebase_analytics: 10.5.0
```

Step 2: Run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.

Step 3: `cd` to `ios` directory and run `pod update`.

I just fixed the problem by following the 3 steps mentioned above.

Comment: Remember that if you are using Apple Silicon chip, the command on step 3 should be something like this `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Comment: It did not work for me :(

Comment: @ashish-rana make sure you dont have any `^` before version. They should be defined sctrictly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with a Flutter project reason was that I have copied a custom repository from another project, and that repository contains a pubspec.yaml file, that generates 3 other files when you are getting dependencies for this pubspec.yaml file.

I have just deleted those files, in my case:

.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
pubspec.lock
and it generated new ones, after that everything worked perfectly.

Maybe it helps someone else...

Answer (score 0):

Check your podfile for anything like this `pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.15.0'`

I had that line, deleting it resolved my issue.